# Error using `loess.smooth` but not `loess` or `lowess`

Tags: r, smoothing, loess

I need to smooth some simulated data, but occasionally run into problems when the simulated ordinates to be smoothed are mostly the same value. Here is a small reproducible example of the simplest case.

```
> x <- 0:50
> y <- rep(0,51)
> loess.smooth(x,y)
Error in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, FALSE, FALSE, normalize = FALSE,  : 
   NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

`loess(y~x)`, `lowess(x,y)`, and their analogue in MATLAB produce the expected results without error on this example.  I am using `loess.smooth` here because I need the estimates evaluated at a set number of points. According to the documentation, I believe `loess.smooth` and `loess` are using the same estimation functions, but the former is an "auxiliary function" to handle the evaluation points.  The error seems to come from a C function:

```
> traceback()
3: .C(R_loess_raw, as.double(pseudovalues), as.double(x), as.double(weights), 
   as.double(weights), as.integer(D), as.integer(N), as.double(span), 
   as.integer(degree), as.integer(nonparametric), as.integer(order.drop.sqr), 
   as.integer(sum.drop.sqr), as.double(span * cell), as.character(surf.stat), 
   temp = double(N), parameter = integer(7), a = integer(max.kd), 
   xi = double(max.kd), vert = double(2 * D), vval = double((D + 
       1) * max.kd), diagonal = double(N), trL = double(1), 
   delta1 = double(1), delta2 = double(1), as.integer(0L))
2: simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, FALSE, FALSE, normalize = FALSE, 
   "none", "interpolate", control$cell, iterations, control$trace.hat)
1: loess.smooth(x, y)
```

`loess` also calls `simpleLoess`, but with what appears to be different arguments.  Of course, if you vary enough of the y values to be nonzero, `loess.smooth` runs without error, but I need the program to run in even the most extreme case.

Hopefully, someone can help me with one and/or all of the following:

1. Understand why only `loess.smooth`, and not the other functions, produces this error and find a solution for this problem.
2. Find a work-around using `loess` but still evaluating the estimate at a specified number of points that can differ from the vector x.  For example, I might want to use only `x <- seq(0,50,10)` in the smoothing, but evaluate the estimate at `x <- 0:50`.  As far as I know, using `predict` with a new data frame will not properly handle this situation, but please let me know if I am missing something there.
3. Handle the error in a way that doesn't stop the program from moving onto the next simulated data set.

Thanks in advance for any help on this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For part 1:**
This took a bit of tracking down, but if you do:

`loess.smooth(x, y, family = "guassian")`

the model will fit. This arises due to the different defaults of `loess.smooth` and `loess`; the former has `family = c("symmetric", "gaussian")` whilst the latter has it reversed. If you trawl through the code for `loess` and `loess.smooth`, you'll see that when `family = "gaussian"` `iterations` is set to `1`. Otherwise it takes the value `loess.control()$iterations`. If you do iterations in `simpleLoess`, the following function call returns a vector of `NaN`:

```
pseudovalues <- .Fortran(R_lowesp, as.integer(N), as.double(y), 
            as.double(z$fitted.values), as.double(weights), as.double(robust), 
            integer(N), pseudovalues = double(N))$pseudovalues
```

Which causes the next function call to throw the error you saw:

```
zz <- .C(R_loess_raw, as.double(pseudovalues), as.double(x), 
            as.double(weights), as.double(weights), as.integer(D), 
            as.integer(N), as.double(span), as.integer(degree), 
            as.integer(nonparametric), as.integer(order.drop.sqr), 
            as.integer(sum.drop.sqr), as.double(span * cell), 
            as.character(surf.stat), temp = double(N), parameter = integer(7), 
            a = integer(max.kd), xi = double(max.kd), vert = double(2 * 
                D), vval = double((D + 1) * max.kd), diagonal = double(N), 
            trL = double(1), delta1 = double(1), delta2 = double(1), 
            as.integer(0L))
```

This all relates to robust fitting in Loess (the method). If you don't want/need a robust fit, use `family = "gaussian"` in your `loess.smooth` call.

Also, note that the defaults for `loess.smooth` differ from those of `loess`, e.g. for `'span'` and `'degree'`. So carefully check out what models you want to fit and adjust the relevant function's defaults.

**For part 2:**

```
DF <- data.frame(x = 0:50, y = rep(0,51))
mod <- loess(y ~ x, data = DF)
pred <- predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x = c(-1, 10, 15, 55)))
mod2 <- loess(y ~ x, data = DF, control = loess.control(surface = "direct"))
pred2 <- predict(mod2, newdata = data.frame(x = c(-1, 10, 15, 55)))
```

Which gives:

```
> pred
 1  2  3  4 
NA  0  0 NA 
> pred2
1 2 3 4 
0 0 0 0
```

The default won't extrapolate if that was what you meant. I don't see what the problem with using `predict` here is at all, in fact.

**For part 3:**
Look at `?try` and `?tryCatch` which you can wrap round the loess fitting function (`loess.smooth` say), which will allow computations to continue if an error in `loess.smooth` is encountered.

You will need to handle the output of `try` or `tryCatch` by including something like (if you are doing this in a loop:

```
mod <- try(loess.smooth(x, y))
if(inherits(mod, "try-error"))
    next
## if here, model work, do something with `mod`
```

I would probably combine `try` or `tryCatch` with fitting via `loess` and using `predict` for such a problem.

Comment: deleted my answer, as that's the same you posted now.

Comment: @Joris - no need to have deleted it. I was about to upvote your answer!

Comment: I've added something on part 1 of the OP's Question as to why `loess.smooth` fails with the sort of problem shown.

Comment: @Gavin : no prob, yours is far more complete. I'm trying to save some server space on the SO site ;-).

Comment: Thanks so much for the very helpful and thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I encountered these functions so I can't help you that much, but can't this have something to do with having a variance of 0 in the y-values? Now you try to estimate a smooth line from data that already is as smooth as it gets, and this does work:

```
x <- 0:50
y <- c(rep(0,25),rep(1,26))
loess.smooth(x,y)
```